# Cannot interpolate vm.value in template - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, attributes

I am updating and modifying a project using Angular JS 1.2.25.

I have my controller where I have a value called `vm.stageValue` which is then called in template with an `ng-if`, so when the `vm.stageValue` increments it shows different containers. But whhen I define a value on the `vm` object that I want to interpolate on the template, eg a string that will be used and will not change on the template, I cannot seem to get it display.

This has makes me think I have not set up my controller correctly using the `vm` method.

It seems weird that I can use the `ng-if` and call function from the controller using `ng-click` on the template but I cannot interpolate a string or send it to another child component

Code is below, thank you in advance. Any help would be hugely appreciated

**Controller**

```
angular
    .module('formModule')
    .controller('NewBusinessFormCtrl', [
        function() {
            let vm = this;

            // Methods used in controller
            vm.methods = {
                incrementStageValue: incrementStageValue,
                decrementStageValue: decrementStageValue,
                canIncrement: canIncrement,
                canDecrement: canDecrement
            };

            //Initial stage values
            vm.stageValue = 1;
            vm.maxStageValue = 7;
            // This is the string that I want to interpolate below
            vm.contactFormCategory = 'New Business'; 
        }
    ]);
```

**Template of Controller**

```
<div class="new_busines_cf" ng-controller="NewBusinessFormCtrl as vm">
<div class="form_wrapper">
    <div ng-if="vm.stageValue == 1">
        <input-text
            class="form_input"
            ng-model="ngModel"
            input-text-label="This is the label">
        </input-text>

        // I want to send the vm.contactFormCategory into the component  
        // Value is sending but the component display 'vm.contactFormCategory'
        // Not the value set in the controller
        <form-headline
            form-headline-sup-title="vm.contactFormCategory"
            form-headline-text="This is a form headline text">
        </form-headline>
    </div>

    // Trying to interpolate value here into template, but nothing display
    {{vm.contactFormCategory}}

    <div ng-if="vm.stageValue == 2">
        <input-text
            class="form_input"
            ng-model="ngModel"
            input-text-label="This is the label of stage 2">
        </input-text>

        <form-headline
            form-headline-sup-title="vm.contactFormCategory"
            form-headline-text="This is a form headline text">
        </form-headline>
    </div>

    <button ng-click="vm.methods.incrementStageValue()">Increment Value</button>
    <button ng-click="vm.methods.decrementStageValue()">decrement Value</button>
</div> 
</div>
```

** Form Headline **

```
angular
    .module('formModule')
    .directive('formHeadline', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/partials/form/form-headline.component.html',
            scope: {
                formHeadlineText: '@',
                formHeadlineSupTitle: '@'
            },
            link: function () {

            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: should be `ng-controller="NewBusinessFormCtrl as vm"`

Comment: Missed that when i was pasting the code back in, it still doesnt work when It is there

Comment: include your `form-headline` component code in your post

Comment: I have added the component, but there is nothing special in the file just two string inputs. I can't get the value to be displayed in my parent directive let alone the child one yet @JohnVelasquez

Comment: try doing like this `{{ ::vm.contactFormCategory }}`

Answer (score 0):

Change your **`ng-if`** to

```
  <div ng-if="vm.stageValue === '2'">
```

Comment: That value is not a string though, would this effect anything to do with my question?